# webtatic php mbstring add module to centos6.6

Tags: php, centos6, mbstring

I have been using  webtatic php 5.4.34 release to develop facebook apps but came to an abrupt halt with this error
—————————-
PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function Facebook\HttpClients\mb_strlen() in /var/www/html/facebook/src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php on line 306
—————————-

It needs the mbstring module (this was added to a facebook php function to resolve an http header problem and cant be commented out which i was hoping to do)

Webtatic instructions mentioned a point in the install where I may have a chance to select php modules to install, but having already installed php54w I decided to upgrade to php56w in the hope this option to use mbstring would appear.

So I have now upgraded to centos 6.6 and then tried to install the php56w but get this well known Error: php56w-common conflicts with php54w-common-5.4.34-1.w6.x86_64.

The solution worked for php54w but as you can see not this time, can you suggest a fix

Also, is there a better way to resolve the missing mbstring module

```html
[root@SECURE21 html]# rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
Retrieving https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
Preparing… ########################################### [100%]
package webtatic-release-6-5.noarch is already installed
[root@SECURE21 html]#
[root@SECURE21 html]#
[root@SECURE21 html]# yum install php56w php56w-opcache
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk
* extras: mirror.econdc.com
* updates: centos.openitc.uk
* webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
–> Running transaction check
—> Package php56w.x86_64 0:5.6.2-1.w6 will be installed
–> Processing Dependency: php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.2-1.w6 for package: php56w-5.6.2-1.w6.x86_64
–> Processing Dependency: php56w-cli(x86-64) = 5.6.2-1.w6 for package: php56w-5.6.2-1.w6.x86_64
–> Processing Dependency: php56w-cli = 5.6.2-1.w6 for package: php56w-5.6.2-1.w6.x86_64
—> Package php56w-opcache.x86_64 0:5.6.2-1.w6 will be installed
–> Running transaction check
—> Package php56w-cli.x86_64 0:5.6.2-1.w6 will be installed
—> Package php56w-common.x86_64 0:5.6.2-1.w6 will be installed
–> Processing Conflict: php56w-common-5.6.2-1.w6.x86_64 conflicts php-common Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php56w-common conflicts with php54w-common-5.4.34-1.w6.x86_64
You could try using –skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va –nofiles –nodigest
[root@SECURE21 html]#
[root@SECURE21 html]#
[root@SECURE21 html]# yum install yum-plugin-replace
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk
* extras: mirror.econdc.com
* updates: mirror.for.me.uk
* webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Package yum-plugin-replace-0.2.7-1.ius.el6.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[root@SECURE21 html]# yum replace –enablerepo=webtatic-testing php-common –replace-with=php56w-common
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace
Replacing packages takes time, please be patient…
Error: Package ‘php-common’ is not installed.
[root@SECURE21 html]#
```

Comment: try it after doing a > yum install php-common

Comment: this happens quiet a bit, you can also try to do a > yum erase php php-pear php-mysql php-cli php-common and confirm with y
to get rid of the old install and its components then do a > yum install php56

Comment: I fixed it doing yum install php54w-mbstring. Now the facebook code runs fine. Its all too obvious after many hours of looking too deep!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it doing yum install php54w-mbstring. Now the facebook code runs fine. Its all too obvious after many hours of looking too deep!

Comment: that's great. this happened to few of my servers a couple of times, it only happened when I upgrade from a lower version of php to a higher version. the first time i got a conflict was because i had older version of php residue that i needed to get rid of then do a reinstall by getting the correct repository on centos 6. there were times where i basically had to get the right package to install for certain apps without getting php warning. i'm glad you figured it out.